# Will my A1522 iPhone 6 Plus work in New Zealand?

Tags: iphone

I know this looks like a very simple and even dumb question, as it would be very easy to check the bands in the website, but it looks that there is something wrong in the specs:

Under [Ultrafast LTE](https://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/), Apple says that the A1522 model doesn't work in New Zealand:

In the [iPhone 6 Plus - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP706?locale=en_US), Apple says that the supported bands of the model are "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 13, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 28, 29". In the Wikipedia page (and other ones), is said that the LTE bands used in New Zealand are 3, 7, 28.

So will my A1522 iPhone 6 Plus work in New Zealand?

Comment: The top of apple's Ultrafast LTE list does disclaim that there may be more combinations, and suggests consulting the carrier for more details.

Answer (score 1):

After arriving on New Zealand and being using Spark carrier for six months, I can say with confidence that the iPhone 6 Plus A1522 works, in both 3G and 4G networks.